# Got OOM issue with google colab

Tags: keras, google-colaboratory

I am building a keras model to run some simple image recognition task. If i do everything in raw Keras, I don't hit OOM. However, strangely, when I do it through a mini framework I wrote, which is fairly simple and mainly so that I can keep track of the hyperparameters and setup I used, I hit OOM. Most of the executions should be the same as running the raw Keras. I am guessing somewhere I made some mistakes in my code. Note that this same mini framework had no issue running with CPU on my local laptop. I think I will need to debug. But before that, anyone has any general advice?

Here's a few lines of the errors I got:

```
Epoch 1/50
2018-05-18 17:40:27.435366: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:898] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2018-05-18 17:40:27.435906: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1344] Found device 0 with properties: name: Tesla K80 major: 3 minor: 7 memoryClockRate(GHz): 0.8235 pciBusID: 0000:00:04.0 totalMemory: 11.17GiB freeMemory: 504.38MiB
2018-05-18 17:40:27.435992: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1423] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2018-05-18 17:40:27.784517: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:911] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2018-05-18 17:40:27.784675: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:917]      0 
2018-05-18 17:40:27.784724: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:930] 0:   N 
2018-05-18 17:40:27.785072: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1041] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 243 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: Tesla K80, pci bus id: 0000:00:04.0, compute capability: 3.7)
2018-05-18 17:40:38.569609: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:275] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 36.00MiB.  Current allocation summary follows.
2018-05-18 17:40:38.569702: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:630] Bin (256):   Total Chunks: 66, Chunks in use: 66. 16.5KiB allocated for chunks. 16.5KiB in use in bin. 2.3KiB client-requested in use in bin.
2018-05-18 17:40:38.569768: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:630] Bin (512):   Total Chunks: 10, Chunks in use: 10. 5.0KiB allocated for chunks. 5.0KiB in use in bin. 5.0KiB client- etc. etc

2018-05-18 17:40:38.573706: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1273] OP_REQUIRES failed at cwise_ops_common.cc:70 : Resource exhausted: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[18432,512] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc
```

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by running out of GPU memory as it is clear from the Warnings.

First workaround is that you can allow GPU memory to grow if possible by writing making this Config proto and passing to tf.session()

```
   # See https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/using_gpu#allowing_gpu_memory_growth 
config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
```

Then pass this config to the session that is causing this error. Like

```
tf.Session(config = config)
```

If this doesn't helps, you could disable the GPU for that particular session that is causing this error. Like this

```
config = tf.ConfigProto(device_count ={'GPU': 0}) 
sess = tf.Session(config=config)
```

If you are using keras, you can get the backends of keras and apply these configs by extracting the session.

Comment: I ran it again today and it worked. I think this GPU memory is a hard one for google colab and you can't really expand it. But I assume your ans. will be useful if you have a GPU with enough memory, will give it a try once i have my own GPU.